# AWS Lambda and Google Drive Push Notification integration possible?

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to receive google drive push notifications if coded on aws lambda via api gateway? 
Google drive requires the webhook address to be verified so is it possible to verify api gateway endpoint?

Here are the possible ways of verifying the endpoint:
1) Upload a file and test via /file  and the rest are below:
[image]

Well, here is the image of how google does metatag verification: In order to get the required verification meta tag, I need to first enter which url/endpoint I want to verify. So below image shows the endpoint that I created:

[image]

Then here in webmaster I am verifying the url: But the verification fails. 
[image]

Here is the python code that I added[image]

Please guide here of how I can make verification successful!

Comment: hey Akshita, can you please help me, how can I achieve this scenario?
I want my lambda function to notice the change on Google drive!
one more thing, I'm facing an issue with is, to read a file from G-drive, I'm able to do it from local machine bu can't read it from lambda function, and the actual error is redirect_uri related, what should be the redirect_uri to set in OAuth setting of Google console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working finally.

So as mentioned by @Balaji and @Jack Kohn, I have to use custom domains. I followed this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

And the last step of mapping body templates is here:

[image]

Sorry for so many cuttings but had to hide the values provided.

Answer (score 2):

@Atihska, it seems you have setup this API:

```
https://x8f3******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/google-endpointverification
```

From what I understand, Google Drive's HTML tag verification method will try to verify the metadata in the **home page**. As per Google, the home page here is:

```
https://x8f3******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

But the above URL won't work because it doesn't have a stage name (like "prod") in it.

The right way to do this would be to use a custom domain name. So, you will need to buy a domain name like foodomain.com and use [custom domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) name option in API Gateway to point to your API. That way, you can make **foodomain.com** (home page) to point to **https://x8f3******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/google-endpointverification**

Also, you can simply use [Mock integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html) instead of Lambda as this is just static content.

Comment: So I used custom domain and setup. This custom subdomain: samplesubdomain.xyz.com is mapped to api gateway endpoint: https://x8f3******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/google-endpointverification. Now after this, do I have to map the cloud front url with the custom domain? As when I created it from api gateway by adding certificate details, it took me to a page specifying the cloudfront url and asked me to create an alias resource record with my DNS provider to map samplesubdomain.xyz.com to d16a0***.cloudfront.net. But I have mapped samplesubdomain.xyz.com to api gateway endpoint.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It isn't an answer but wanted to insert a picture as I cannot insert in a comment and the original question is filled with them. I have added API mappings to custom domain but now I am getting 'Missing Authentication Token'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure how the registration process works for verifying the webhook address, but it is certainly possible to configure the webhook itself in API Gateway.

API Gateway supports [custom domain names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) like ***api.example.com*** if Google doesn't accept the default API domain name.

Edit:

Based on those options, it seems like you could use the default endpoint xxxx.execute-api...amazonaws.com if you configure the HTML meta tag.

You could do this by setting up a GET method on I guess the root resource that is a MOCK integration. That integration response can return static content, so in the integration response section you could paste whatever HTML Google is looking for. You would probably also need to set the response 'Content-Type' header to 'text/html'.

Comment: Kohn I have updated my question and added the methods supported by webmaster for verification. Could you confirm if we can verify the aws api endpoint that we own it?

Comment: Updated... custom domain name would work with the domain name provider option. I expect the HTML meta tag option should work with the default endpoint, you'll just need to configure that.

Comment: Kohn I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Kohn For the HTML Meta tag option, we require a homepage where we will add the endpoint. Where is the homepage for the AWS api gateway endpoint?

Comment: There is no 'homepage' but the API is totally generic. You can configure a resource/method in the API to return HTML. I'm assuming that will work since Google is probably just parsing the HTML response from whatever endpoint you give it.

Comment: Kohn I have updated my question here, added some trials. Could you please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

@Balaji I was able to figure our API mapping in order to link custom subdomain with the API. But I get 'Missing Authentication token' when I use https://api.example.com, in this case lambdanotifications.***.com. I also tried lambdanotifications.***.com/notifications and lambdanotifications.***.com/notifications/test on browser but same thing.

[image]